# How do I construct a button that is positioned over another button?

Tags: jquery

I am working with a homebrewed grid in which each element is a button.  Templates are used  for the button styling and look something like this:

```
<div id='cellTemplate'>
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

As you can see above, the template is constructed with a containing div which is replicated for each cell.  Inside, can be anything, but in most cases, there is a 'p' tag with some text content.

What I'd like to do is construct a delete button, but the problem I am having is that clicking the delete button also fires the click handler on the containing div.  I would like to create a delete button that does not appear to fire the containing div's click handler.

I've created the sample html, which so far, has not worked out.

```
<div id='cellTemplate'>
    <p>some content</p>
    <div class='deleteButton'>(X)</div>
</div>
```

Due to the construction of the framework, 'cellTemplate' will, by default, have a click handler assigned to it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) is used for exactly this purpose.  It prevents the event from bubbling up to parent elements.

```
$("something").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `event.target` and manage events from a "cell" or "row" if it fits into your app better

There is extra code in here than needed just for discussion purposes

```
$('.cellTemplate').click(function( event){
    var tgt=event.target;   
    var tagName=tgt.tagName;                                  
    var $tgt=$(tgt);    

    if( tagName=='p' ){
        $tgt.doAnEdit();
    }else if( $tgt.is('.delete')){
        $(this).parent.remove();
    }
})
```